# Not understand result from $(window).width()

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, width

I have several pages and I notice one strange moment, this code:

```
var w = $(window).width();
alert(w);
```

- sometimes returns result: 1440, (and this is true, my screen resolution is 1440 x 900)
- sometimes (in different pages) returns: 1423.

From whence this result, I dont understood.

`$(window).width()` must be always (from all pages) return the same result, mustn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The scrollbar is not included. From your results, `1440 - 1423 = 17px`, which is the same width as my scrollbar (e.g. here on Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 2):

It returns 1423 when you have the scrollbar visible.

The width returned when the scrollbar is visible might change on different browsers and operating systems.